# Is there any infinite loops?

Tags: valgrind, callgrind

I have run the program without the `valgrind` and it just ended fine just in a minute.

When I try to run in through the `callgrind(valgrind --tool=callgrind)`, the program is never ended(at least for a six hour), and here is the `top` command output

```
 PID USER      PR  NI %CPU    TIME+  %MEM  VIRT  RES  SHR S COMMAND
 3722 vhovhann  17   0   75  52:38.95 13.5 10.4g 9.6g  34m R callgrind-amd64
  PID USER      PR  NI %CPU    TIME+  %MEM  VIRT  RES  SHR S COMMAND
 3722 vhovhann  17   0  100  53:21.40 13.6 10.4g 9.6g  34m R callgrind-amd64
```

I am wondering why the program is not ended with the valgrind?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the program. For instance, if you are using threads, the program might have got stuck in a deadlock since threads behaves different on Valgrind (Valgrind serializes threaded applications).